# Firebase Cloud Storage Pricing Confusion

Tags: firebase, flutter, cloud, storage

I'm a little confused with the calculation of costs with Firebase Cloud Storage in this page.
https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

I am currently programming a fitness app in which you can watch a 5-10 second video for each exercise.
This is more than 100 videos that I would like to store in Firebase Cloud Storage.

Now my problem is that I do not know exactly what is meant here as "download". Does downloading count as watching a video or when you actually download the file?

Cloud Storage has the following numbers:
Cloud Storage:
No-cost               Pay as you go
GB stored                          5 GB                 $0.026/GB
GB downloaded                     1 GB/day             $0.12/GB
Upload operations                 20K/day              $0.05/10k
Download operations               50K/day               $0.004/10k

What is the difference between GB downloaded and Download operations?

An example so I understand.
If my 100+ videos are all around 10 MB, then they don't even take up 1 GB anyway, that shouldn't cost anything.
Let's say my app has 5 million users and they watch 20 of these videos every day.
Then I would have 100 million requests per day.

Would the calculation be correct?
100.000.000 / 10k download operations = 10000 * $0.004 = $40 per month ?
That looks wrong somehow. It can't be that cheap.

And all my JSON files are there too, requested by the user.
There are additional costs per request.

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reference, the actual [pricing page for GCP Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing). It states its 3 components of billing:

- Data storage: what you actually have stored in your buckets
- Data processing: operations done by GCP to get your files
- Network usage: mostly egress I assume in your case

> What is the difference between GB downloaded and Download operations?

You'll be charged for the size of your bucket, files transfered (network) and the data processing operations mentioned above. GCP splits operations in different cost categories, [see list here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#process-pricing). When Firebase talks about "Upload operations" they mean "Class A operations" and "Download operations" are "Class B operations".

"GB downloaded" is your network usage.

> Would the calculation be correct? 100.000.000 / 10k download operations = 10000 * $0.004 = $40 per month ? That looks wrong somehow. It can't be that cheap.

You miss the network bandwidth, see [network pricing](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#network-egress). It's staggered and depends on region but the cheapest rate is **8 ct per GB**. For your daily **100M requests of 10MB each**, you would have bandwidth costs of at least **80,000 USD per day**.

Edit:

I assumed the [Firebase pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) is misleading or overly simplified. But network usage is just labeled as "GB downloaded". It states 0.12 ct per GB (which is the standard rate, but the actual pricing varies between 8-19 ct according to GCP Cloud Storage pricing tables). So you still have to pay for your traffic of 1,000 TB per day.

Comment: So then I think this is not a good way to store the videos at all.
What about Youtube? I think then that Youtube is the better alternative for something like that?
What are the costs?
Because then I would leave my JSON files in Firebase storage and the videos in Youtube.

Comment: This is a bit off-topic for StackOverflow; but you could use YouTube as long as you're ok with all the implications (it's their video player, their ads, their platform, etc.). Then it's just a matter of embedding your YT videos.

Comment: I have one last question about Firebase Cloud Storage.
Does this calculation of costs also count for all other file types? Like JSON files for example?

For example, if a JSON file that takes only 1 Mb of storage is accessed 10 times a day per user, with 5 million users. Then the calculation would be correct as follows?

5.000.000 * 10 = 50.000.000 requests
50.000.000 / 1000 Mb = 50.000
50.000 * 0.08 = 4000 USD per day?

Comment: Yes, Cloud Storage (or any other solution like AWS S3) does not care what file type an object is. Your calculation is correct in terms of bandwidth, but lacks what Firebase calls "download operations". That being said, if the JSON file can be public, you might be better off storing it on a CDN or storing the actual JSON data in a database.